# How to select item in List view

Tags: list, swiftui

I have following code in SwiftUI

```
struct AuthorView: View {

let authors = ["a","b","c"]
@State private var selectedAuthor = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Authors").font(.title)
        HStack {
            List(authors, id: \.self, selection: $selectedAuthor) {author in
                Text(author).tag(author)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't compile due to error "Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred". What I'm doing wrong here? My aim is to get selected author for later use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` selection by interface contract should be optional, so here is fixed part

```
struct AuthorView: View {

   let authors = ["a","b","c"]
   @State private var selectedAuthor: String?      // << !!

// ... other code
}
```